# JQuery scroll to title top space with Bootstrap navbar fixed top

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I create a `<a href="activity-areas/#autonomous-mobile-robot-systems">` link on the home page.  I want to go to a partition on another page with this link. So, autonomous title of the activity areas page. Is working, but title under the bootstrap navbar fixed top.

Homepage

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 featured">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 featured-box">
        <a href="activity-areas/#autonomous-mobile-robot-systems">
        <h1>test 1</h1>
        <img class="img-responsive featured-image" src="#" alt="" title=""/>
        </a>
        <div class="featured-content">
            <p>
                Aenean vel tempor ex. Proin et ante ex. Aliquam sed.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 featured-box">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>test 2</h1>
        <img class="img-responsive featured-image" src="#" alt="" title=""/>
        </a>
        <div class="featured-content">
            <p>
                Aenean vel tempor ex. Proin et ante ex. Aliquam sed.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 featured-box">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>test 3</h1>
        <img class="img-responsive featured-image" src="#" alt="" title=""/>
        </a>
        <div class="featured-content">
            <p>
                Aenean vel tempor ex. Proin et ante ex. Aliquam sed.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Activity Areas Page

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <ul class="services-list">
            <li><a href="#autonomous-mobile-robot-systems">Otonom Mobil Robot Sistemleri</a></li>
            <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="widget-title" id="autonomous-mobile-robot-systems"><span>autonomous-mobile-robot-systems</span></h2>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <p>asdf</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="widget-title" id="three"><span>three</span></h2>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <ul>
                <li>asdf</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This section is directed on this page. But the title is under the navbar.
I want to give space overhead heading 120 px.

Script

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 120
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Works on the links on activity areas page. No space in the top referrers to this page redirect from homepage.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey .. sorry but how will this code fire? If a link is clicked and redirects to the hash section on another page wont this code be negated ... because its on the previous page?

Comment: Yes the previous page. However, working on GitHub issue structure. So what are the importance of having the properties on the previous page?

Comment: Um , sorry you lost me , Github what? The problem i see here right. .. You have a click event that fires on a `<a>` which redirects to another page. So all the code below will ( maybe i am wrong, i dont know your whole codebase ) not ever be used in the DOM

Comment: Is your site up? If so, give us a link so that we could test it live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my script as follows.

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 120
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == 'activity-areas/') {

        var target = $(window.location.hash).offset();
        if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(target)) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.top - 120
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

It was a bad solution, but it solves the problem.Until better :)